I have a code that is erroring because of null safety in flutter
how can this code be null safty?
this is the code
class FoodTitleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String productName;
  String productPrice;
  String productHost;

  FoodTitleWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.productName,
    @required this.productPrice,
    @required this.productHost,
  }) : super(key: key);


Just remove @ annotation it's deprecated, and pass the key directly to the parent class constructor.
  FoodTitleWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.productName,
    required this.productPrice,
    required this.productHost,
  });

